# How to smooth graph curves

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I am drawing graphs based on an excel data and I have average value, minimum value, and maximum value. The problem is that when I draw a graph the curves are not smooth and it is very hard to understand. I am using matplotlib to draw a graph

[GoogleDrive: data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Okl-jDIRisbDmZKuxRpLd_3KKwNgVf8/view?usp=sharing)

**Columns in Excel data Like**
[image]

**Code**

```
# libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
# Data
df_Data = pd.read_csv('/home/khawar/Downloads/wandb_export_2021-10-09T14_05_20.127+09_00.csv')
print(df_Data.head())

# df = pd.DataFrame(
#    {'x_values': df_Data['Step'], 'y1_values': df_Data['VIT - loss__MIN'], 'y2_values': df_Data['VIT+OverLP (Ours) - loss__MIN']})

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x_values': df_Data['Step'], 'y1_values': df_Data['VIT - acc'], 'y2_values': df_Data['VIT+OverLP (Ours) - acc']})

font = {'family': 'serif',
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 'normal',
        'size': 11,
        }

# multiple line plots
# plt.plot('x_values', 'y3_values', data=df, color='green', linewidth=1.5, label="ResNet-18")
plt.plot('x_values', 'y2_values', data=df, color='blue', linewidth=1.5, label="hello")
plt.plot('x_values', 'y1_values', data=df, color='red', linewidth=1.5, label="hi")

# plt.rcParams["font.weight"] = "bold"
# plt.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"
# plt.xticks(weight='bold')
# plt.yticks(weight='bold')

# Display y axis values
# ax = plt.gca()
# ax.set_ylim([0.0, 10.0])

plt.xlabel('Number of iteration', fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Training loss', fontdict=font)
# plt.ylabel('Average accuracy (%)', fontdict=font)

plt.savefig('/media/khawar/HDD_Khawar/Thesis/deeplearning_acc.png')
plt.legend()

# show graph
plt.show()
```

Result
If you will see the graph curves are not smooth and I just want to smooth it[image]

Comment: Correctly import with `.read_csv`, use `.rolling` to smooth the data, and plot the dataframe directly: [resulting code & plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPuki.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can plot a smooth curve by first determining the spline curve’s coefficients using the `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline()`

```
# Dataset
x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
y1 = np.array([20, 30, 5, 12, 39, 48, 50, 3])

x2 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
y2 = np.array([2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3])

X_Y_Spline1 = make_interp_spline(x1, y1)
X_Y_Spline2 = make_interp_spline(x2, y2)

# Returns evenly spaced numbers
# over a specified interval.
X_1 = np.linspace(x1.min(), x1.max(), 500)
Y_1 = X_Y_Spline1(X_1)

X_2 = np.linspace(x2.min(), x2.max(), 500)
Y_2 = X_Y_Spline2(X_2)

# Plotting the Graph
plt.plot(X_1, Y_1)
plt.plot(X_2, Y_2)
plt.title("Plot Smooth Curve Using the scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline() Class")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There is only one y-axis value, I have two values, my excel data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Okl-jDIRisbDmZKuxRpLd_3KKwNgVf8/view

Comment: I edited my answer for multiple XY.

Comment: Could you please follow my data? because you are taking static data NumPy array.